# Random redirect to wp-admin/install.php

Tags: redirect, installation

My website redirects to wp-admin/install.php sometimes. This came on all of a sudden. And sometime website is working fine.

Any ideas on why it could be redirecting to that? How to resolve it?

Comment: WP will do this if it doesn't find database tables, do you have special logic in your `wp-config.php` messing with those values? Have you made modifications to files in `wp-includes` or `wp-admin`?

Comment: No sir i have just made modification in `wp-config.php` in this i change `debug ` to true from false